# Three row layout with two background-images in the main element and centered content

Tags: html, css

1. I tried to create a three-row layout with a dynamic footer. The height of the footer should be using the "rest" of the screen, as the other two parts have fixed height values. Right now the footer isn't shown at all:

```css
 body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
 }
 header {
   background-color: red;
   height: 70px;
 }
 main {
   background-color: green;
   height: 30%;
 }
 footer {
   background-color: blue;
 }
 #left_image {
   background-image: (left.jpg);
   height: 100%;
   /* auto width for proper image scaling */
 }
 #right_image {
   background-image: (right.jpg);
   width: 50%;
   /* auto height for proper image scaling */
 }
 #content {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 3em 1em;
   z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <div id="left_image"></div>
    <div id="right_image"></div>
    <div id="content">This content is in front of the background-images</div>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

2. I want to put two background images on the left and right side of the `main` container and the content of `main` should be centered (horizontally and vertically) and be in front of the background images. How do I do that best? I tried to use container with `background-image`. Do I really have to use three-div container?

Comment: More: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/skcdug6k/3

Comment: Thanks. That helps, but the content should be centered into the main-container on top of the images (by the way: the right image should be on the right side of the container). And how do I make the footer going completely to the bottom?

Comment: I changed the height/width of `main` and the images in the post.